# Average.if on several sheets raises an error

Tags: excel

I have sheets from 1 to 12.

AVERAGE('1:12'!K4) works but AVERAGE.IF('1:12'!K4;">0") doesn't.

I encounter the same problem with the sum.

Comment: What is that `.` doing? Shouldn't it just be `AVERAGEIF([Range],[Criteria])`

Answer (score 2):

There are a limited number of functions that work with "3d ranges" - Neither `AVERAGEIF` nor `SUMIF` are on that list. You can get the sum like this:

`=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}&"'!K4"),">0"))`

and average like this

`=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}&"'!K4"),">0"))/SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}&"'!K4"),">0"))`